# How to wait for above dialog to disappear before clicking on element behind it in single page application

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I have to enter a zip code in a dialog box. Once the button is clicked to enter the zip code, I try to wait for the prompt to close before clicking a different button but it can't properly wait for the next button to be clicked while the prompt is closing. 
[Example of dialog before closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWglF.jpg)

Reasons include the following:

I can't use waitForSelector(" ", {visible:true}) because the selector is already visible behind the initial dialogue.

I can't use waitForNavigation because closing the initial tab doesn't change the page.

I am trying to avoid manually waiting a set amount of time before the page loads.

I also tried to wait for the above dialog to become null but it happens too quickly before the next button is actually clickable.

```
//await self.page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("div.shopping-context-container") == null');
```

I want to know if there is a way to wait for the next button to actually be clickable when there is an above dialog trying to close.

```
await enterInput.click(); // Submit zip code
await self.page.waitForSelector("button#nav-shopping-selector-postalcode", {
    visible: true,  // This automatically is true because the selector is already visible behind the prompt 
  }); 
  let zipcodeButton = await self.page.$(
    "button#nav-shopping-selector-postalcode",
    {
      visible: true,
    }
  );
  await zipcodeButton.click(); // Clicks next button before page is properly loaded
  await self.page.waitForSelector("input#shopping-selector-postal-code", {
    visible: true,
  });
  // Breaks here because the second button wasn't clicked and so there is no node for this selector
  await self.page.type("input#shopping-selector-postal-code", zip);
```

Comment: what do you mean by clickable? is this the overlay issue?

Comment: If I were to do zipcodeButton.click(), it will not do anything and won't return an error unless the prompt above the button has properly disappeared. Once the prompt is gone, zipcodeButton.click() will work as intended and open the next prompt. The issue is knowing when to click this button after the prompt disappears since there is some lag time between the above prompt being null and the button behind it clicking as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the right idea:

```
await self.page.waitForFunction(() => !document.querySelector("div.shopping-context-container"))
```

But I can't tell if that div is getting removed or just hidden.

Comment: It does get removed and set to null but it happens before the element behind is actually clickable due to it being slow to respond I believe.

Comment: You would need to  find out what changes about the button. Maybe it was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches come into my mind:

1. If it's not necessary to use emulated mouse click, and the only issue is the overlay blocking the click, you can use `HTMLElement.click`:

```js
await page.evaluate(el => el.click(), zipcodeButton);
```

2. Check whether the element is on top using `elementFromPoint`:

```js
const {x, y} = await zipcodeButton.boundingBox();

const isOnTop = await page.evaluate((x,y, selectedElement) => {
    let topElement = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    return topElement === selectedElement;
}, x, y, zipcodeButton);

if (isOnTop)
    await zipcodeButton.click();
```